# How to make jQuery slideToggle() for the list?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I try to make a list of panels with same toggle-effect. But I get just first working element. How can I make it for the list?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
#flip {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #e0ebeb;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #66c2ff;
}
```

JS:

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <apex:repeat value="{!ObjList}" var="list">
    <apex:outputPanel id="panelId">
        <div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up {!list.Id}</div> 
<div id="panel">Hello {!list.Name}!</div>
      </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a class or other attribute, as id should be unique on each page. In this example, we changed the ID selectors to class selectors, then we use next to find the next sibling, and alter its properties. The precise syntax you require will depend on the structure of your page, so you might also need to use parent/find or other combinations to get your code working.

Here's a working example of your code from my org.

---

```
<style>
    .flip {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #e0ebeb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #66c2ff;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".flip").click(function(){
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
<apex:repeat value="{!ObjList}" var="list">
    <apex:outputPanel id="panelId">
        <div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up {!list.Id}</div> 
        <div class="panel">Hello {!list.Name}!</div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:repeat>
```